# Auto Regex Generator - Similarity Between 2 strings c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex generator for scrapping purposes, and any guidance is appreciated.

The idea is that we have a big text (html), we select 2 (at least) DOM elements that are always similar (like the first 2 results from google) and than we should generate a regular expression that will scrape (match) this results.

Example:
Selected element 1 (this will be inputed by a user):

```
<a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNHqQo9TrXtXXM5lDpiCmNQO9xwkhw','','0CGoQFjAA',null,event)" class="l" href="http://www.miniclip.com/"><em>Games</em> at Miniclip.com - Play Free Online <em>Games</em></a>
```

Selected element 2 (this will be inputed by a user):

```
<a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNGlNySkvcXMxEUmjCMOJRQPCdqBHQ','','0CHIQFjAB',null,event)" class="l" href="http://www.games.com/"><em>Games</em>.com: Play <em>Games</em> Online - Free <em>Games</em>, Download <em>Games</em> <b>...</b></a>
```

HTML text that contains both elements:

```
<ol id="rso" eid="GcrGT_KHH4f3sgbXmci5Cw"><!--m--><li class="g"><div sig="U8P" bved="0CBUQkQo" pved="0CBQQkgowAA" class="vsc"><h3 class="r"><a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNHqQo9TrXtXXM5lDpiCmNQO9xwkhw','','0CGoQFjAA',null,event)" class="l" href="http://www.miniclip.com/"><em>Games</em> at Miniclip.com - Play Free Online <em>Games</em></a></h3><div class="vspib" aria-label="Detalii rezultat" role="button" tabindex="0">

</div></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div sig="fUe" bved="0CBsQkQo" pved="0CBoQkgowAQ" class="vsc"><h3 class="r"><a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNGlNySkvcXMxEUmjCMOJRQPCdqBHQ','','0CHIQFjAB',null,event)" class="l" href="http://www.games.com/"><em>Games</em>.com: Play <em>Games</em> Online - Free <em>Games</em>, Download <em>Games</em> <b>...</b></a></h3><div class="vspib" aria-label="Detalii rezultat" role="button" tabindex="0">
```

In this case, the good regex would be:

```
(<h3 class="r">)(.*?)(</h3><div)
```

Not to hard to figure out. The problem appears when `<h3 class="r">` appears in another element that is not related to our results. For example if you add:

```
<h3 class="r">THIS IS JUST AN EXTRA THING</h3>
```

at start of the HTML text, the regex from above would not work.

The new regex would need to be:

```
(class="vsc"><h3 class="r">)(.*?)(</h3><div)
```

I know this is not an easy thing to acheieve, but my idea is to find the similarities of the elements (for example take 100 characters before and after the elements and see what are identical for element 1/element 2).

Hope somebody can guide me on what would be the best way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know that there is a whole research behind this. This is not a simple problem. I think it has been done in a paid add-ons for Excel.

Comment: It sounds like the actual problem you're trying to solve is: "Given a webpage, find any sequence of repeated tags that *might* be a list of data". Regex probably isn't the answer. Maybe some kind of autocorrelation (in the DSP sense) on the tags?

Comment: Just to provide more details for a possible solution. I tried implementing a DIFF algorithm. I take 2 elements that have similar patterns, copy 50 characters before and after both elements, compare the differences and create the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the first thing that you need is something that returns a regular expression that optimally fits a particular string, given that string (and some context).  Seems like there are a few options out there including [Regulazy](http://osherove.com/blog/2006/7/9/introducing-regulazy-point-amp-click-regular-expressions.html) and [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/).

The next thing that you need is the ability to traverse the DOM, because you're looking for a parent (for example given 2 links in your example you want to find the surrounding h3).  You can try to do this via regex, but it will be difficult and you probably won't handle all the edge cases appropriately.  There are all kinds of tools available for both fixing non XML compliant HTML and traversing the resulting DOM, for example I was doing this in Java the other day using [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/).

At that point you can apply an algorithm like the following:

1. Find the first common parent between the two given nodes.
2. Build a regular expression from the text contents of the parent.
3. Apply the regex to the contents of the top level html node.
4. If you get more than 1 match (the double h3 case) zoom out to the parent's parent.
5. Rinse and repeat, starting at step 2 with the new parent.

The secret sauce is clearly in how you generate the regex from the string, but it sounds like you can lean on some third party tools for that portion.  In essence what you're doing is creating a string to regex compiler, so if you need to implement this from scratch one approach may be tokenizing the string and building an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).  You can then [visit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) the AST nodes to run optimizations (for example looking for duplicate consecutive nodes that can be replaced with regex */+ operators), and then in a final visit generate the regex.

At a higher level, you may want to think about whether regular expressions are really the correct answer for your problem.  If you just want to find links on Google given a few examples, you can probably just traverse the DOM to look for the parent and then grab all the children that are links.